# Subclasses of a class that implements a generic interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, gwt

I'm working with Google Web Toolkit, and I'm having problems implementing a generic interface. I'm not really familiar with generics, doing an upgrade on someone else's code here.

Here's what I want to do: I want to have an implementation of a generic callback interface that does some logging, and then subclass that implementation in order to handle specific callback scenarios.

The interface is something like this:

```
public interface AsyncCallback<T> {
    void MethodFromAsyncCallback(T result);
}
```

The abstract and concrete implementations look something like this:

```
class CallbackBase implements AsyncCallback<Object> {
    public abstract void doStuff(Object result);

    public void MethodFromAsyncCallback(Object result) {
        // IMPORTANT STUFF
        // here are things I would like to do for all callbacks, hence the superclass.

        // Then we do the subclass specific things.
        doStuff(result);
    }
}

class SpecificCallback extends CallbackBase
{
    public void doStuff(Object result) {
        Integer i = (Integer)result;
        // do stuff with i
    }
}
```

The callbacks are required to be fired from

```
public interface MyServiceAsync {
    public void DoSomeThing(AsyncCallback<Integer>);
}
```

And then it all comes together in a call that looks like this:

```
MyServiceAsync myService = (MyServiceAsync)GWT.create(MyServiceAsync.class);
myService.DoSomeThing(new SpecificCallback());
```

**And here's where we have a problem!**

When the `GWT.create()` implements the interface I created, it demands that the type given to `AsyncCallback` is specified (matches a type elsewhere, outside the scope of this question), hence making `DoSomething(AsyncCallback<Integer>)` an Integer rather than an Object. This is beyond my control.

It complains that `DoSomething()` takes `AsyncCallback<Integer>`. I'm giving it something that inherits from something that is an `AsyncCallback<Object>`. I guess with generics, concepts of inheritance get somewhat broken?

**So my question is this:**

*Either* how can I mush this together so that `DoSomething()` will recognize that that `SpecificCallback` meets it's requirements,

*or* how can I structure the relationship between `CallbackBase` and `SpecificCallback` so that duplicate code is avoided, but `SpecificCallback` implements `AsyncCallback<Integer>` directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I think you need to do is define `CallbackBase` like this:

```
abstract class CallbackBase<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
  public abstract void doStuff(T result);

  public void MethodFromAsyncCallback(T result) {
    // general stuff (T is a subclass of Object)
    doStuff(result);
  }
}
```

Then you want your specific callbacks to be like this:

```
class SpecificCallback extends CallbackBase<Integer> {
  public void doStuff(Integer result) {
    // no need to cast
    // do stuff with result
  }
}
```

Then your `DoSomething` method, which accepts an `AsyncCallback<Integer>`, will accept a `SpecificCallback`.

(Pedantic sidenote: please start all methods with lowercase letters in Java)

**Edit**

For what it's worth, I'd suggest changing your design to use composition rather than inheritance. In this case, rather than using an abstract class `CallbackBase` and extending it, you'd use a concrete implementation of `AsyncCallback<T>` that might look something like this:

```
class GeneralCallbackWrapper<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
  private final AsyncCallback<? super T> delegate;

  public GeneralCallbackWrapper(AsyncCallback<? super T> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public void MethodFromAsyncCallback(T result) {
    // general stuff here
    delegate.MethodFromAsyncCallback(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Re: edit. Yes, that makes a lot of sense. I wanted to alter it to something like that in the first place, but figured I'd address my confusion one step at a time. ;)

Comment: Is it possible to extend either of these to account for two possible types? e.g. conceptually equivalent to `implements AsyncCallback<Integer>, AsyncCallback<OtherType>`?